# Render errror in Navigating after signout user #ReactNative #react #Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, render, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[GitHub](https://github.com/kaushalpandey1510/trek-tracker-app)

React Native App, As of now project consists of SignIn, SignUp, and Sign Out. So basic idea of my signout function Removes token from local device with AsyncStorage and dispatch an action and at last navigate to loginFlow (Signup screen)

Below are the thing I've tried...

1. In AuthContext comment on everything and displayed a log with a message to make sure the right function is called onPress.
2. The error is somewhere in rendering the page loginFlow, when I replaced the loginFlow with TrackList, that was successfully completed. Also, a thing to note is that I get an error in rendering the Signup page, but the token from local storage was cleared, which means AsyncStrorage is working fine!
3. Tried our old method of putting a callback as a prop, but same error!

**Error**

TypeError: _reactNative.Dimensions.removeEventListener is not a function. (In '_reactNative.Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this.handleOrientationChange)', '_reactNative.Dimensions.removeEventListener' is undefined)

This error is located at:
in withDimensions(undefined) (created by TabNavigationView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by TabNavigationView)
in TabNavigationView (created by NavigationView)
in NavigationView (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
in NavigationContainer (created by _default)
in Provider (created by _default)
in _default (created by withDevTools(_default))
in withDevTools(_default)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)

https://github.com/kaushalpandey1510/trek-tracker-app

I get the similar error while I signout out the user and navigate them to main flow!

**AccountScreen.js** [src/screens/AccountScreen.js]

onPress={signout} calls signout function defined in AuthContext.js

**AuthContext.js** [src/context/AuthContext.js]

signout function succesfully removes the token from asyncStorage but I get above error on navigate.

though I'm using same navigate to in signin and signup and they work perfectly fine!

Also the navigate used in AuthContext.js is navigation library made to give navigation access to the files not included in App.js. navigationRef.js is the file

Answer (score 1):

In AuthContext.js

import {NativeModules} from "react-native";
.....

and use `NativeModules.DevSettings.reload()` instead of `navigate("loginFlow")`

Comment: The same error appeared for me after an update. This solution worked for me, while others didn't.